# C++ Adding big numbers together with operator overload

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am new to C++ and attempting to create a "BigInt" class. I decided to base most of the implementation on reading the numbers into vectors.

So far I have only written the copy constructor for an input string.

```
Largenum::Largenum(std::string input)
{
 for (std::string::const_iterator it = input.begin(); it!=input.end(); ++it)
    {
      number.push_back(*it- '0');
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is with the addition function. I have created a function which seems to work after I tested it a few times, but as you can see its highly inefficient. I have 2 different vectors such as:

```
std::vector<int> x = {1,3,4,5,9,1};
std::vector<int> y = {2,4,5,6};
```

The way I thought to solve this problem was to add 0s before the shorter, in this case y vector to make both vectors have the same size such as:

```
x = {1,3,4,5,9,1};
y = {0,0,2,4,5,6};
```

Then to add them using elementary style addition.

I don't want to add 0s infront of vector Y as it would be slow with a large number. My current solution is to reverse the vector, then push_back the appropriate amount of 0s, then reverse it back. This may be slower then simply inserting at the front it seems, I have not tested yet.

The problem is that after I do all of the addition on the vectors and push_back the result. I am left with a backward vector and I need to use reverse yet again! There has got to be a much better way then my method but I am stuck on finding it. Ideally I would make A const as well. Here is the code of the function:

```
Largenum Largenum::operator+(Largenum &A)
{
    bool carry = 0; 
    Largenum sum;                

    std::vector<int>::size_type max = std::max(A.number.size(), this->number.size());
    std::vector<int>::size_type diff = std::abs (A.number.size()-this->number.size());

    if (A.number.size()>this->number.size())
    {
        std::reverse(this->number.begin(), this->number.end());
        for (std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i<(max-diff); ++i) this->number.push_back(0);
        std::reverse(this->number.begin(), this->number.end());
    }
    else if (this->number.size() > A.number.size())
    {
        std::reverse(A.number.begin(), A.number.end());
        for (std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i<(max-diff); ++i) A.number.push_back(0);
        std::reverse(A.number.begin(), A.number.end());
    }
    for (std::vector<int>::size_type i = max; i!=0; --i)
    {
        int num = (A.number[i-1] + this->number[i-1] + carry)%10;
        sum.number.push_back(num);
        (A.number[i-1] + this->number[i-1] + carry >= 10) ? carry = 1 : carry = 0;
    }
    if (carry) sum.number.push_back(1);

   reverse(sum.number.begin(), sum.number.end());

   return sum;
}
```

If anyone has any input that would be great, this is my first program using classes in C++ and its fairly overwhelming.

Comment: If you want front insertions like that, you might be better off with `std::deque`. I won't comment on the algorithm that entails that choice.

Comment: yes, I was looking into deque. Ideally I would find a way that didn't require any front insertions as I suspect vector will be faster.

Comment: Just a suggestion. You might be interested in http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigInteger.java

Comment: Reversing the number is not a great idea. Either store it "back to front" and just fix it up when displaying, or calculate it "from the back forwards"

Comment: I did try to calculate it "from the back forwards" but couldn't manage to do it without doing an insertion of zeros. Would a reverse iterator be the correct tool here?

Comment: Note that of the four basic arithmetic operators, three of them (when done by hand on paper) work from least-significant to most-significant digit - only division starts with the most-significant digit(s). So, an LSD-first storage order will probably make more of the algorithms you intend to implement simpler...

Comment: Small point, but consider making your copy constructor take the input by reference, const std::string & input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your function is quite close to the most optimal one I have seen. Still here are few suggestions how to improve it:

- Decimal numeric system is quite inefficient, you have a lot of digits for big numbers. Better use a higher base to reduce the number of digits you have to add. Reading and writing such numbers in human readable representation will be a bit harder, but you will optimize the operations several times, because you will have less digits.
- When implementing big integers I represent them in reverse order, thus I have the least significant digit at position with index 0, and the most significant one at the end of the array. This way when carry forces you to add a new digit you only perform a `push_back`, not a whole reverse.

Comment: thanks, I understand your second point and I am going to change my code to read into the vectors the other way. I don't however know what you mean by going to a higher base? Do you mean convert the numbers to a higher base in the vectors, then on output convert them back?

Comment: @UserAce yes you got my idea right. For instance if you use base 1000000 your numbers will have 6 times less digits which will result in 6 times faster computation of sums.

Answer (score 0):

One issue: integer modulus is pretty slow on modern processors, even compared to branch misprediction. Rather than doing an explicit %10, try this for your third for-loop:

```
int num = A.number[i-1] + this->number[i-1] + carry;
if(num >= 10)
{
    carry = 1;
    num -= 10;
}
else
{
    carry = 0;
}
sum.number.push_back(num);
```